# Mathematical symbols as keywords in listing

Tags: listings, wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to use mathematical symbols as keywords in listing? I'm using `listings` package to typeset Mathematica code and I have used `emph` parameter of `lstset` to use blue bold font for some of my functions like

```
\lstset{
    emph={CoolFun1, CoolOp2},
    emphstyle={\color{blue}\bfseries}
}
```

I would like also to use some functions named with mathematical symbols, \eg\ Greek names like $\delta$ and so on. So the goal is to have something like

```
\lstset{
    emph={CoolFun1, $\delta$},
    emphstyle={\color{blue}\bfseries}
}
```

and obtain Mathematica listings with bold blue mathematical symbols.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A feature of `listings` that can come in handy in these situation is the `literate` option.

If you are happy with writing `delta` in your listing instead of `$\delta$` and get it replaced with the symbol by `listings` then here's a solution:

```
\lstset{
    literate={
        {delta}{{$\color{blue}\delta$}}1
    }
}
```